# javascript calculation based pie chart graph

Tags: javascript, html

In **Cash Needs at Death** Div total 7 lists there,if i enter any value in these any field automatically calculated done but i need pie chart for this total value . The total value is under the code **Cash Needs at Death :**  And Again Div2 if i enter any amount it will calculating ,here total 3 values will come dynamically , I need pie chart for this . once check below html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
}

th {
    height: 50px;
}
            #summation {
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: bold;
                /*color:#174C68;*/
            }
            /*.txt {
                background-color: #FEFFB0;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: right;
            }*/
            </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="section-space bg-box">
            <div class="container menu-list-wrapper">
            <h2>Our Calculator</h2>

        <!--<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>-->




<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">Cash Needs at Death</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td>Final and Medical Expenses <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt11"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Outstanding Mortgage Balance <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt12"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Other Debt to Pay Off <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt13"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Education Fund <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt14"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Estate Transfer Costs <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text"  name="txt15"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Charitable Contributions <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt16"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Emergency Fund <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt17"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<br>


<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">Income for Survivors</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td>Monthly Income Needed <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt1" type="text" name="txt1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Years to Provide Income <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt1" type="text" name="txt1"/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Assumptions</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Anticipated Rate of Return <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt1" type="text" name="txt1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Anticipated Inflation Rate <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td><input class="txt1" type="text" name="txt1"/></td>
    </tr>


</table>

<br>

<!--<form name="form1" method="post" action="" >-->
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">Current Resources</th>
  </tr>
<tr><td>Current Assets: <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td><td><input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Current Life Insurance Available: <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td><td><input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" /></td></tr>
<!--<tr><td>Sum: <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td><td><input type="text" name="sum1" id="sum1" readonly /></td></tr>-->
<!--<tr><td>Subtract:</td><td><input type="text" name="subt" id="subt" readonly /></td></tr>-->
</table>
<!--</form>-->




   <table>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Life Insurance Needs</th>
  </tr>
<tr id="summation">

        <td align="right">Cash Needs at Death : <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td align="right">Cash for Survivor Income : <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum2">0</span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">Current Resources</th>
  </tr>
<tr><td>Sum: <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf156;</i></td><td><input type="text" name="sum1" id="sum1" readonly /></td></tr>
</table>







  <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
    </script>


    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    sum1();
    $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum1();
    });
});

function sum1() {
            var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
            var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('sum1').value = result;
                document.getElementById('subt').value = result1;
            }
        }
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

I need all these 3 values graph dynamically like below link 
https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/

Am attaching the image also please check [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did a search for you this package is neat and free
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html
 and as you see it is easy to use